# Cannot delete a 2.2mb partition

Tags: partitioning

I downloaded u torrent in ubuntu and then I uninstalled it. But it has created a 2.2mb volume and I cannot delete anything from that volume.

command ls -la
gives

```
̀̀̀total 88
drwxr-xr-x 18 cheran cheran 4096 Mar 22 15:43  .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root   4096 Mar 22 13:31  ..
-rw-------  1 cheran cheran 1386 Mar 27 18:21  .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 cheran cheran  220 Mar 22 13:31  .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 cheran cheran 3771 Mar 22 13:31  .bashrc
drwxrwxr-x 15 cheran cheran 4096 Mar 22 14:35  .cache
drwx------ 16 cheran cheran 4096 Mar 27 17:57  .config
drwxr-xr-x  2 cheran cheran 4096 Mar 22 14:34  Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  3 cheran cheran 4096 Mar 23 12:02  Documents
drwxr-xr-x  2 cheran cheran 4096 Mar 27 18:18  Downloads
drwx------  3 cheran cheran 4096 Mar 27 18:30  .gnupg
drwxr-xr-x  3 cheran cheran 4096 Mar 22 14:34  .local
drwx------  5 cheran cheran 4096 Mar 22 14:35  .mozilla
drwxr-xr-x  2 cheran cheran 4096 Mar 23 10:47  Music
drwxr-xr-x  2 cheran cheran 4096 Mar 22 14:34  Pictures
-rw-r--r--  1 cheran cheran  807 Mar 22 13:31  .profile
drwxr-xr-x  2 cheran cheran 4096 Mar 22 14:34  Public
drwxr-xr-x  5 cheran cheran 4096 Mar 27 17:15  snap
drwx------  2 cheran cheran 4096 Mar 22 14:37  .ssh
-rw-r--r--  1 cheran cheran    0 Mar 22 15:32  .sudo_as_admin_successful
drwxr-xr-x  2 cheran cheran 4096 Mar 22 14:34  Templates
drwxr-xr-x  2 cheran cheran 4096 Mar 22 14:34  Videos
drwxrwxr-x  2 cheran cheran 4096 Mar 27 18:18 'VirtualBox VMs'
```

and command sudo fdisk -l
gives

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 54.98 MiB, 57626624 bytes, 112552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 55.48 MiB, 58159104 bytes, 113592 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 106.45 MiB, 111611904 bytes, 217992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 218.102 MiB, 229629952 bytes, 448496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 61.65 MiB, 64626688 bytes, 126224 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 255.58 MiB, 267980800 bytes, 523400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 62.9 MiB, 65105920 bytes, 127160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 49.8 MiB, 52203520 bytes, 101960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000DM010-2EP1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4F481D7A-0E09-4985-A954-0988F7A0A7FA

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1          34      32767     32734    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2       32768  651194367 651161600 310.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3   651194368 1302355967 651161600 310.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  1302355968 1953521663 651165696 310.5G Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 223.58 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: ADATA SU650NS38 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B47C682B-14DE-4B57-B69E-BF4C5A5E8AB8

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1    1085440   1288191    202752    99M EFI System
/dev/sdb2    1288192   1320959     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb3    1320960 291259690 289938731 138.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4  291260416 292313087   1052672   514M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb5  292315136 468860927 176545792  84.2G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/loop8: 64.79 MiB, 67915776 bytes, 132648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 32.28 MiB, 33841152 bytes, 66096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 51.4 MiB, 53522432 bytes, 104536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 32.28 MiB, 33845248 bytes, 66104 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 2.7 MiB, 2166784 bytes, 4232 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 99.48 MiB, 104304640 bytes, 203720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 337.72 MiB, 354107392 bytes, 691616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Please help me out with this!!!

Comment: What does gparted show, information on this partition?

Comment: I dont have gparted

Comment: Actually you do I guess I should have been much more clear, Boot from live media and run gparted.

Comment: I installed gparted just now, but I cant any 2.2mb partition in it

Comment: GPART is a advanced tool...We need to know what you have tried to delete files from the disk and how you access it. Can you type `ls -la`

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: You don't have a 2.2MB partition.  That's just a snap mounted so it can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no actual 2.2MB partition in your system, hence why you don't see it in `gparted` or any of the partition tools.

The `loop` mounts are Snap mounts.  You cannot 'remove' or 'delete' them and they aren't actually partitions, they're the Snap applications loaded up and usable.

If you want to remove the `loop` mounts you have to uninstall the corresponding snaps.  You can't remove all the snaps, though, because that'll break your system.

You don't actually *have* a 2.2MB partition.  That's just a Snap mounted so it can be used.

If you are absolutely certain this is a utorrent snap, then you need to remove it.  `sudo snap remove utorrent` should remove the application *and* the snap mount.

Comment: "You can't remove all the snaps, though, because that'll break your system." citation needed, I removed all the snaps from my system.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'mma just leave this output of `sudo snap list` on a 20.04 system [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Vdnfwnx3cT/) for you to review, as GNOME Core on 20.04 systems (and 18.04) are snapped now.  Unless you use a different Desktop Environment, you're going to break the DE on a vanilla Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank The Ceiling for Ubuntu MATE!